# Как сделать так чтобы при клике на другую кнопку закрывался input?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

У меня есть выбор из 4 кнопок, 3 кнопки чтобы выбирать определённую сумму, и 1 для Другой суммы, когда нажимаю на Другую сумму, появляется инпут снизу, но не могу сделать так чтобы при клике на кнопку состоящей из фиксированной суммы, пропадал инпут для ввода другой суммы

```
const Pay = ()=>{
    
    const amounts = [ 5, 10, 15 ];
    const [ amount, setAmount ] = useState(null);
    const [ isCustomAmount, setIsCustomAmount ] = useState(false);
    
    return(
        <>
             <div className={styles.wrapper}>
          <div className={styles.container}>
         
          <form action="https://app.0xProcessing.com/Payment" method="post" >
            <input  type="hidden" name="test" value="true" />
             <input type="email" name="email" placeholder='Email' required />
             <input type="text" name="currency" placeholder='Валюта'  required />

            <div className={styles.mid}>
            <div   className={styles.choice}>
             {amounts.map((value)=>{
               return(
                   
                  <label  key={value}>
                  <input   type="radio" value={value} disabled={isCustomAmount} checked={amount === value && !isCustomAmount}
                    onChange={() => setAmount(value)}  
                  />
                  <span>{value}$</span>
                </label>              
               )
             })}
                        
               <label > <input  className={styles.word_opts} type="checkbox" checked={isCustomAmount} style={{display: 'none'}}
               onChange={e => (setAmount(null), setIsCustomAmount(e.target.checked))}  />
                <span className={styles.span}>Другая сумма</span>
               </label>
               </div>
                      {isCustomAmount && <input value={amount} onChange={e => setAmount(+e.target.value)} placeholder='Введите сумму'  />}
                     
            </div>
            

             
               <input type="hidden" name="ShopId" value="6QsQHcQ6bX" />
               <input type="hidden" name="ClientId" value={payKey.data} />
              <input type="hidden" name='SuccessUrl' value={`https://next-js-web-sandy.vercel.app/success/`}/>
              <input type="hidden" name='AutoReturn' value="true" />
              <button type="submit">Send</button>
          </form>       
          </div>
         </div>
         <h1 className={styles.heading}><Link href={`/`}><button>Назад</button></Link></h1>
        </>
    )

}

export default Pay
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На мой взгляд, правильный вариант, это объединить все radio в одну группу и работать в рамках нее

```
<div className={styles.mid}>
  <div className={styles.choice}>
    {amounts.map((value)=>{
      return(

        <label  key={value}>
          <input name={'val'}  type="radio" value={value}
                 onChange={() => {
                   setIsCustomAmount(false);
                   setAmount(value)
                 }}
          />
          <span>{value}$</span>
        </label>
      )
    })}
    <label  key={'any'}>
      <input name={'val'}  type="radio" value={'any'}
             onChange={(e) => {
               setIsCustomAmount(true);
               // Нужно заменить этот рандом на значение 
               // или стирать значение переменной amount
               setAmount(Math.round(Math.random() * 20)); 
             }}
      />
      <span>{'Другая сумма'}</span> </label>


  </div>
  {isCustomAmount && <input name={'inputVal'} value={amount} onChange={e => setAmount(+e.target.value)} placeholder='Введите сумму'  />}

</div>
```

При клике на "Другая сумма", будет отображаться поле ввода. Так у вас для суммы определена переменная **amount**, то при отображении поля, будет подставляться предыдущее выбранное.

Я поставил random для теста, вам надо эту строчку заменить на желаемое значение.

Comment: Тестировал [в песочнице](https://codesandbox.io/s/korzina-pokupok-l2e2uy?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Здраствуйте, благодарю за ответ, могу ли я оставить пустым setAmount() вместо рандомного числа ```setAmount(Math.round(Math.random() * 20))```  @SwaD, это никак не повлияет на другие значения?

Comment: @Jalil Тогда уж лучше передавайте пустую строку `setAmount('')`

Comment: есть одна несостыковка, в каждом инпуте должен быть ```name={'amountusd'}```,  но кроме инпута который выполняет фунцию кнопки,  а если ```name```  у всех будет разный то всё что вы написали перестаёт работать

Comment: пожалуйста помогите решить это @SwaD

Comment: По **name** идет группировка `input type='radio'`. А у `input type='text'` должен быть другой. Поправил в ответе.

Comment: я всем инпутам дал **name** amountusd, так как это необходимое название для них, чтобы платёжный провайдер принимал их как платёж, но я и ```<input  name="amountusd"  type="radio" value={'any'} onChange={(e) => { setIsCustomAmount(true) setAmount("")}}``` присвоил **name** amounusd, это не изменит значение которое будет отправлено? @SwaD

Comment: Может быть конфликт. Для radio дайте другое имя

Comment: если убрать с radio **name**  amountusd,  то они все потеряют смысл в использовании, так как они предназначены для выбора суммы, а если отсутствует amountusd, то платёжный провайдер не будет получать их значения @SwaD

Comment: Тогда может вам не стоит использовать input type='radio'? Может достаточно нарисовать несколько div вместо них, где по клику будет записываться нужная сумма в поле? Т.е. вам надо отделить логику выбора суммы от передаваемого поля.

Comment: Для меня это займёт времени, поэтому пока что не буду трогать код, большое спасибо что помогли с этим, выручили :) @SwaD